# Error testing any component with Ionic ion-infinite-scroll as child (Ionic 4)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic4, ng-mocks

First off, this isn't a *breaking* issue, but I do not like the fact that running my unit tests is presenting an error. So anyways, if you create a page/component with Ionic and use the `ion-infinite-scroll` component, and then proceed to unit test this component, there will *always* be an error such as this:

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined thrown
```

Now this won't fail the test suite but it does show in the console and muddies it up. I have tried to mock this child component using [ng-mocks](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks) but this still seems to present itself. I am using [spectator](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator) with the default setup with Jasmine. I do not think this issue is related to using these tools. Does anyone have any idea on how to properly mock the `ion-infinite-scroll` component so test suite does not call methods on the actual component?

Here is what I've tried:

```
describe('SomePage', () => {
  let spectator: Spectator<SomePage>;

  const infiniteScrollStub = {
    complete: jasmine.createSpy('complete')
  };

  const createComponent = createRoutingFactory({
    component: SomePage,
    declarations: [
      IonInfiniteScroll
    ],
    providers: [
      { provide: IonInfiniteScroll, useValue: infiniteScrollStub }
    ],
    params: {}
  });

  beforeEach(() => spectator = createComponent());

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(spectator.component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

===

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined thrown
```

---

```
describe('SomePage', () => {
  let spectator: Spectator<SomePage>;

  const infiniteScrollStub = {
    complete: jasmine.createSpy('complete')
  };

  const createComponent = createRoutingFactory({
    component: SomePage,
    declarations: [
      MockComponent(IonInfiniteScroll)
    ],
    params: {}
  });

  beforeEach(() => spectator = createComponent());

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(spectator.component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

===

```
Error: Multiple components match node with tagname ion-infinite-scroll
```

The test passes on the first example with the ugly error at the end.
The test fails on the second example with that reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just want to leave a comment here for anyone who comes across this. Not sure if it's the correct answer, but  if I use `MockModule(IonicModule)` instead of importing the `IonicModule` as-is, I don't get this error anymore.

Comment: This is the correct answer and you can post and accept it. Frameworks have a lot of things under the hood and the best way to turn them into mocks is to mock their modules instead of declarations.

Answer (score 0):

creds to @SpellChucker

In tests, only SUT shouldn't be mocked. So the right way is to mock `IonicModule`: `MockModule(IonicModule)`, to suppress its requirements for environment and logic.